# Macro without parenthesis

Tags: c++

is it possible to define macro which takes argument not closed in parenthesis?
I would like to simplify my ECS system so the user can create component class without manually coding template inheritance stuff.

So the macro could look like the code below, but I don't want it to have parenthesis:

```cpp
#define ECSComponent(ClassName) struct ClassName : public Component<ClassName>

ECSComponent MyComponent {
    //members
}
```

Comment: Arguments to macros must be provided in parenthesis. Having said that, I don't quite see any value in this macro at all.

Comment: Arguments about its utility aside, it's a fair question.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I do not see how it is a useful questions, even utility aside. The question is 'language syntax is X, can I do Y instead' to which the answer is **No**. And it is not the one where 'Language forbids X, how can I achieve it' either.

Comment: @JesperJuhl How would you use a function to introduce a class name and its base class, while leaving the surrounding code free to define its members?

Comment: @SergeyA What's wrong with a question to which the answer is "no"?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit depends on type of No, in my opinion. When the question is simply 'can you do something in the manner which is contrary to one prescribed in language spec' I do not see much value in it. But it's just me.

Comment: @SergeyA Depends whether you already know that the "thing" is not proscribed by the language spec. This OP didn't. A thing isn't off-topic just because you already know the answer :P

Answer (score 5):

No, you cannot change the syntax of function-like macros in C++.